# What are you using for getting stats about your web app? G. Analytics or other solution?

Tags: web-applications, statistics, google-analytics, monitoring

if you are building your own web application, what are you using for monitoring of visitors.  Are you getting this information from Google Analytics?  Or do you prefer your own solution?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer Piwik: http://de.piwik.org/

Comment: Wow, I didn't know it... it's surprise for me. 
I will check out Piwik.

Comment: This is not true. Try to inform yourself before making statements like this, http://www.advanced-web-metrics.com/blog/2011/06/16/google-analytics-and-the-new-eu-privacy-law-2/